# Getting "NullReference Exception" error while creating new organizational unit using Get-ADOrganizationalUnit]

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

Below is section of a large script that configures range of tasks remotely on a Active Directory server.

The script asks the user to enter OU name, saves it in a variable and passes it to AD server via `Invoke-Command` and `$Using` scope to transfer variable value to remote host and process the request

```
$value = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Unique Name"

Invoke-Command -Session $testsession -ScriptBlock { 

        $DDN = "DC=Test,DC=net"
        $OUdn = "OU=MainOU,"+$DDN
        $COU = $Using:value
        $Cdn = "OU="+$COU
        $CPath = $Cdn+","+$OUdn             
        
        While ($true) {
                Write-Host "Checking existence of OU"                              
                if (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "distinguishedName -eq '$CPath'") {
                    Write-Host "$COU OU exists."                                                                                                                                                                                     
                    $COU = $Null
                    $Cdn = $Null
                    $Cpath = $Null
                    $COU = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Unique Name"
                    $Cdn="OU="+$CustOU
                    $CPath=$Cdn+","+OUdn                                 
                }else {
                    Write-Host "$COU is new"            
                    New-ADOrganizationalUnit $COU -path $OUdn                           
                    if (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "distinguishedName -eq '$CPath'") {
                        write-host " $COU is created "                          
                    }
                    Break                   
                }               
        }
  }
```

It gives the desired result when it is run separately and creates OU with the name provided under "Main OU". However, when it is combined with the main script it throws exception error. Main script also prompts to enter some more info which are used in other sections successfully but just not working in this section.

Am I missing anything? Your suggestions and helps are appreciated.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit], NullReferenceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADOrganizationalUnit
```

Comment: Can you see what line exactly is throwing that exception? The error *usually* means that something you're trying to reference, hasn't been instantiated first. I ask for line number to give you a better hint of what it may be referring to that you can pin point.

Comment: Hi Abraham, it does not indicate any line number but I believe the issue is with Get-ADOrganizationalUnit cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you understand why you're getting the error and will also help you in future scripts:

```
try
{
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit $COU -path $OUdn
}
catch
{
    @(
        "Failed to create New Organizational Unit:"
        "$_" 
        "Value for `$COU was: $COU"
        "Value for `$OUdn was: $OUdn"
    ) | Out-String | Write-Warning

    break
}
```

For more info: **[about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.1)**

---

As a side note, I don't see `$CustOU` being previously defined and I believe this a typo `$Cdn+","+OUdn`.

Comment: Thank you @Santiago , I used try catch and it is still throwing same error and the catch state does show values for those variables are present and not null.

Comment: @N997 try adding this at the top of your script, on line 1: `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`.

Comment: Thank you @Santiago, it worked this time. However, I am still trying to figure why I am getting that error. I have to review my code from beginning